# Label from view model disappears after submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-post

Why does the `TextFromDb` label disappear after submit?  How do I fix it?  I see that on post it is not in VM.

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var vm = new TestLabelVM();
        vm.TextFromDb = "Text from database";
        return View(vm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(TestLabelVM vm)
    {
        SaveToDb(vm.TextOpinion); 

        return View(vm);
    }
```

My view model:

```
public class TestLabelVM
{
    public string TextFromDb { get; set; }
    public string TextOpinion { get; set; }
}
```

My web page `Index.cshtml`:

```
@model TestLabelVM
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "TestLabel"))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.TextOpinion)
    <br/>
    @Model.TextFromDb
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TextFromDb)
```

inside your form.  This will allow mvc's model binding to... wait for it... bind the value to the model and subsequently display it when the post action renders the view.

Comment: That will persist the value after post back, but it won't display it.

Comment: It's working but if I'm using complex string with url inside of it, it's fail with redirection on another page.

    @Html.Raw(Model.Info)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Info, @Html.Raw(Model.Info))

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment completely, and I don't think that's a valid overload of `HiddenFor`

Comment: If I have url in the text then input is not working "potentially dangerous..". Example: vm.TextFromDb = @"Text from database: <a href=""http://www.blah.com"">Blah</a>";

Comment: Ahh, I see.  You can decorate the POST action with `[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]` to disable that exception.  But be careful, that can open you up to XSS.  You may want to do some research on that, or use a different approach altogether (like re-fetching the string from the database within the post method).

Answer (score 1):

It's because you never save that text anywhere. Only things that the browser posts back to the server (i.e. inputs) can be loaded automatically by the model binder.

Fetch the text from the DB again in your post handler.